Missing mdr_text data in openFDA Device Adverse Events [/device/event] API results
We have noticed that since the openFDA /device/event update on 2024-06-04 the the API results return empty mdr_text fields for all records (e.g., "mdr_text": []). We have not confirmed if other fields are empty.
Query results from MAUDE website include the "Event Text" data, and the json dataset files last updated on 2024-06-08 contain mdr_text data.

This does not seem to be the case:
https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=exists:mdr_text.mdr_text_key
"total": 18814450


The mdr_text field data is now included and working correctly. Thanks for the update, Denis.
